# What is the best way to send back the response from the middle-ware in Golang

Tags: go, middleware

I have created middle-wares using Adapter pattern. One of my middle-ware is for authentication. So if the user is not authorized then I have to send back response to the user and the next middle-ware/s should not be called.

```
// Adapter type

type Adapter func(http.Handler) http.Handler

// Adapt func
func Adapt(h http.Handler, adapters ...Adapter) http.Handler {
    // Call all middleware
    for _, adapter := range adapters {
        h = adapter(h)
    }
    return h
}

// CheckAuth middleware
func CheckAuth() Adapter {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Get Authorization token from the header
            // Validate the token
            // if valid token then call h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            // else send response 401 to the user,
            if(validUser){
                h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            }else{
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unauthorized")
            }
            return h
        }
    }
}

http.Handle("/", Adapt(indexHandler, AddHeader(),
                                 CheckAuth(),
                                 CopyMgoSession(db),
                                 Notify(logger), 
                               )
```

in the CheckAuth middleware I'm calling `h.ServeHTTP(w, r)` only if the user is authorized, so for the else condtition we also need to break the `for` loop of the `Adapt` function or else it will call next middleware even after sending the response.

let me know if there is any other way to handle such situation.

Comment: You don't need to break the loop. The loop is long done by the time the HandlerFunc is called. Simply return without calling h.ServeHTTP.

Comment: Hi @Peter Can you please explain, how the execution will be done if have 3 middleware and I'm sending back response from middle-ware 2

Answer (score 4):

The next middleware in the chain only runs if you *explicitly* call it.

That next middleware is passed to your closure as `h`, and you are calling it by invoking `h.ServeHTTP()`. If you do not call this, no other middleware runs, so you must supply the complete HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

The Adapt function is not relevant for serving requests. It is executed once (and only once) before the HTTP server even starts. Note that it *returns* an http.Handler but it isn't an http.Handler itself.

That handler that Adapt returns in this case behaves like this:

```
var indexHandler http.Handler

func handlerWithMiddleWare(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    notify := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            copyMgoSession := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                    checkAuth := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                            addHeader := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                                    indexHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
                            }

                            addHeader(w, r)
                    }

                    checkAuth(w, r)
            }

            copyMgoSession(w, r)
    }

    notify(w, r)
}
```

So if you let CheckAuth return without calling the next middleware, you can send whatever response you like; just as you would in any other handler.

By the way, you way want to let Adapt iterate in reverse order. I'm not sure that you're aware that Notify executes first, then CopyMgoSession, then CheckAuth, and then AddHeader.

Answer (score 1):

Middleware is typically chained. There are frameworks that can do it for you. A sleek example is [Alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice).

```
chain := alice.New(th.Throttle, timeoutHandler, nosurf.NewPure).Then(myHandler)
```

If you want to do it yourself you can use recursion to avoid a for loop. For example (from this [link](https://gist.github.com/husobee/fd23681261a39699ee37)):

```
// buildChain builds the middlware chain recursively, functions are first class
func buildChain(f http.HandlerFunc, m ...middleware) http.HandlerFunc {
        // if our chain is done, use the original handlerfunc
        if len(m) == 0 {
                return f
        }
        // otherwise nest the handlerfuncs
        return m[0](buildChain(f, m[1:cap(m)]...))
}
```

Each middleware receives the next as parameter. As such the next has to be manually called by the previous handler otherwise the chain stops. So in your auth middleware you don't have to call the next one if auth fails and the chain stops with your error status being the last thing returned. So in your code you need to accept a parameter of `http.Handler` and that is the next handler (a middleware function has to have the signature of `func(http.Handler) http.Handler`). See this [blog](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware) for more details.

You may want to set the correct http status codes as well. Include something like this:

```
http.Error(w, "Forbidden: xyz", http.StatusForbidden)
```

Comment: yes that i have, Just sample code I've written here, even after having sending the http status remaining middle-ware will be invoked by the `for` loop. I want to break the for loop somehow

Comment: hey I'm still confused, I don't see any difference in using recursive function instead of for loop, Can you plz explain the control flow

Comment: gorilla/mux can chain middleware now, so if you're using that then you can probably refactor to get rid of alice.

Comment: I added a sentence about how the middleware chain stops when an auth fails, if that was your question.